# HTML5 Video: Overriding fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

In HTML5, when I click the fullscreen button, is there an event fired I could listen to or a method I could override to change functionality?

I want my player to increase/decrease in size according to predefined values on clicking the button, instead of going fullscreen.

My project uses js, jquery and backbone

Answer (score 1):

In html5 there is no option to have resize or customize the video tag

Instead of this you can use **JPlayer** plugin which you can customize your screen to play your videos without any flaws

http://www.jplayer.org/latest/quick-start-guide/

`$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({`

```
    ready: function(){
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        m4v:"http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v"
    }).jPlayer("play");
    },
    ended: function(){
        $(this).jPlayer("play");
    },
    swfPath: "../../common/assets/jplayer/js",
        supplied: "m4v",
    size: {
        width: "400px",
        height: "30px"
     }
```

});